# Python itertools.product() equivalent in Perl

Tags: python, perl, python-itertools

In Python I can use `itertools.product()` which the documentation says is the "cartesian product, equivalent to a nested for-loop".

What is it's equivalent in Perl?

An example in Python:

```
import itertools
opts_list = [["A","B"], ["C","D","E"], ["F","G"]]
print list(itertools.product(*opts_list))
```

Gives:

> [('A', 'C', 'F'), ('A', 'C', 'G'), ('A', 'D', 'F'), ('A', 'D', 'G'), ('A', 'E', 'F'), ('A', 'E', 'G'), ('B', 'C', 'F'), ('B', 'C', 'G'), ('B', 'D', 'F'), ('B', 'D', 'G'), ('B', 'E', 'F'), ('B', 'E', 'G')]

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Gen

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using:

```
use Math::Cartesian::Product;
cartesian {print "@_\n"} ["A","B"], ["C", "D", "E"], ["F", "G"];
```

Comment: There are some nice suggestions here. I'm sure there should be a better meta-CPAN than [metcapan.org](https://metacpan.org/). I'm tempted to make one myself, but better people than me have tried and failed.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [Algorithm::Loops](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm::Loops)'s `NestedLoops`.

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my $iter = NestedLoops([["A","B"], ["C","D","E"], ["F","G"]]);
while (my @items = $iter->()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The advantage of this solution is its flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Set::CrossProduct](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::CrossProduct):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Set::CrossProduct;

my $it = Set::CrossProduct->new([
     ["A","B"],
     ["C","D","E"],
     ["F","G"]
]);

while (my $v = $it->get) {
    print "@$v\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the CPAN modules referenced in the other answers. But as a fun exercise I wrote my own function to return the cartesian product for any number of input array references.

```
my $combinations = get_combinations(["A","B"], ["C","D","E"], ["F","G"]);

foreach my $combo (@$combinations) {
  print "@$combo\n";
}

sub get_combinations {
  my @arrays = @_;

  # pre-determine to the total number of combinations
  my $total = 1;
  foreach my $aref (@arrays) {
    # if our array is empty, add 1 undef item
    push(@$aref, undef) unless scalar @$aref;
    $total *= scalar @$aref;
  }

  my $matrix = [];
  my $block_size = $total;
  for (my $col = 0; $col <= $#arrays; $col++) {
    # determine the number of consecutive times to print each item in the column
    $block_size = $block_size / scalar @{$arrays[$col]};

    # fill-in our 2-D array (matrix), one column (input array) at a time
    for (my $row = 0; $row < $total; $row++) {
      my $item_index = int($row / $block_size) % scalar @{$arrays[$col]};
      $matrix->[$row]->[$col] = $arrays[$col]->[$item_index];
    }

  }

  return wantarray ? @$matrix : $matrix;
}
```